# Issue with text wrap on IE10 with brackets

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a link in a navigation menu that doesn't wrap properly on IE10.

When there is a conditional plural using brackets, IE10 cut off the word into 2 separated lines. I am expecting the whole word "link(s)" to go to the next line if there is not enough space, like Chrome is doing.

[image]

It's supposed to look like this:

```
Hello worldddd
link(s)
```

I tried to use the different `word-wrap` and `word-break` attribute but it doesn't fix it. If I use `white-space: nowrap`, the word doesn't go to the next line. I don't want to force the word to go to the next line for all browsers.

Do you know what I can do to fix this IE issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a text like this:

```
<p>this is a longer <span class="nowrap">test(s)</span></p>
```

Then all you need to do is apply following CSS:

```
p {
    word-break: break-word;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
{
    /*target IE10*/
    .nowrap {
        white-space: pre;
    }
    /*target IE11*/
    *::-ms-backdrop, .nowrap {
        white-space: pre;
    }
}
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgun6v3z/10/) - you can resize HTML input area to see the difference